# How can I do this loop to print values across (x,y) axes from an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, data-structures, foreach

I have an IEnumerable as below:

```cs
IEnumerable<Object> a;
a = { City = "Houston", Temperature = "80", Season = "Fall"}
    { City = "Chicago", Temperature = "64", Season = "Fall"}
    { City = "San Francisco", Temperature = "70", Season = "Fall"}
    { City = "Houston", Temperature = "101", Season = "Summer"}
    { City = "Chicago", Temperature = "84", Season = "Summer"}
    { City = "San Francisco", Temperature = "90", Season = "Summer"}`
```

I want to print this into an excel sheet
in a `table-format``. X-Axis being the three cities and Y-Axis the Seasons.

How can I form a loop?

Right now, I am printing the x and y axes as:

```cs
var xaxis = a.select(x=>x.City).ToList();

var yaxis = a.select(x=>x.Season).ToList();
List<string> xList = new List<string>();
List<string> yList = new List<string>();
foreach(var y in yaxis)
{
  if(!yList.Contains(y))
  {
    worksheet.cells[rowindex,columnindex].Value = y.ToString();
    yList.Add(y);
  }
}
  columnindex= xcolumn;
  rowindex = yrow;

foreach(var x in xaxis)
{
  if(!xlist.Contains(x))
  {
    rowindex++;
    worksheet.cells[rowindex,columnindex].Value = x.ToString();
    xList.Add(x);
  } 
}
```

I am lost, how to print / loop through the data to print the temperature for each `(city, season)` pair! How can I do this loop correctly?

Comment: You don't show us where you get X and Y?  Please show us the code that matters

Comment: aargh..my bad. y is the season and x is the city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should create a class as Maxim_A pointed out.

Then you can use the below code for a dynamic and readable solution.

```
// change as needed
const int headerRowIndex = 1;
const int headerColumnIndex = 1;

// prepare keys
var cities = a.GroupBy(x => x.City).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
var seasons = a.GroupBy(x => x.Season).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

// set cities
var columnIndex = headerColumnIndex;
cities.ForEach(x => worksheet.Cells[headerRowIndex, ++columnIndex].Value = x);

// set seasons
var rowIndex = headerRowIndex;
seasons.ForEach(x => worksheet.Cells[++rowIndex, headerColumnIndex].Value = x);

// set temperatures
a.ToList().ForEach(x => worksheet.Cells[seasons.IndexOf(x.Season) + headerRowIndex + 1, cities.IndexOf(x.City) + headerColumnIndex + 1].Value = x.Temperature);
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a class with your structure.

```
public class Item
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I took your array, grouped it by city and displayed in tabular form. you have not provided the information with which you write to the Excel file (possibly Excel.Interop), but I work with .XLSX documents use the epplus library. Let me clarify that the numbering of rows and columns in this library begins with one.

Code:

```
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>()
        { 
            new Item() { City = "Houston", Temperature = "80", Season = "Fall"},
            new Item() { City = "Chicago", Temperature = "64", Season = "Fall"},
            new Item() { City = "San Francisco", Temperature = "70", Season = "Fall"},
            new Item() { City = "Houston", Temperature = "101", Season = "Summer"},
            new Item() { City = "Chicago", Temperature = "84", Season = "Summer"},
            new Item() { City = "San Francisco", Temperature = "90", Season = "Summer"}
        };

        var listGroups = from item in list 
                         group item by item.City;

        int count = 2;

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"myworkbook.xlsx");
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
        {
            var workbook = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($"Worksheets_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss")}");


            workbook.Cells[2, 1].Value = "Summer";
            workbook.Cells[3, 1].Value = "Fall";

            foreach (var item in listGroups)
            {
                workbook.Cells[1, count].Value = item.Key;
                foreach (var temp in item)
                {
                    if (temp.Season == "Summer")
                        workbook.Cells[2, count].Value = temp.Temperature;
                    else
                        workbook.Cells[3, count].Value = temp.Temperature;
                }
                count++;
            }
            excelPackage.Save();
        }
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: In my case.. the list is dynamic. I wouldn't know if its 'summer', 'fall' etc.. it was an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3797607/user3797607 , where and in what form do the data come to you then?